# Unable to find dtw_std in mlpy 3.5.0

Tags: python

I was trying to use the mlpy-3.5.0 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS ( Python 2.6.5 ), but after the packages import, at the point I will perform the DTW instruction,
an error happens and the following log is shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtw_std'

An interesting thing also occurs when I was googling about it and found this [relevant topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mlpy-general/7902Ae6soCI): if I replace by `mlpy.Dtw()`, it works!
So I would like some help.

Here is the source code, also provided by the package:

```
import mlpy
x = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0]
y = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0]
dist, cost, path = mlpy.dtw_std(x, y, dist_only=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have the correct mlpy installation.

`sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`
get the tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mlpy, `tar -xvfz mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz`, `cd mlpy-3.5.0` and `sudo python setup.py install`